# cakePHP 3: multi JOIN

Tags: cakephp, associations, inner-join, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I'm having trouble with relationships between tables with CakePHP 3.x. I am struggling to make realcionamento between tables with more than 2 levels realcionamento .
I will introduce the code of relationships and also the query I'm doing to make it more clear what behavior relations:

```
class CircuitosTable extends Table{
        public function initialize(array $config)
        {
            $this->table('circuitos');

            $this->addAssociations([
                'belongsTo' => [
                    'Planostreinos' => [
                        'foreignKey' => 'id_plano_treino',
                        'joinType' => 'INNER',
                        'bindingKey' => 'id'
                    ]
                ],
                'hasMany' => [
                    'Atividades' => [
                        'className' => 'Atividades',
                        'foreignKey' => 'id_circuito',
                        'bindingKey' => 'id',
                        'joinType' => 'INNER',
                        'dependent' => false,
                        'cascadeCallbacks' => false,
                        'propertyName' => '_atividades'
                    ],
                ]
            ]);

        }
    }


class AtividadesTable extends Table{
        public function initialize(array $config)
        {
            $this->table('atividades');

            $this->addAssociations([
                'belongsTo' => [
                    'Tiposexercicios' => [
                        'foreignKey' => 'id_tipo_exercicio',
                        'joinType' => 'INNER',
                        'bindingKey' => 'id'
                    ],
                    'Circuitos' => [
                        'foreignKey' => 'id_circuito',
                        'joinType' => 'INNER',
                        'bindingKey' => 'id'
                    ]
                ]
            ]);

        }
    }

class TiposexerciciosTable extends Table{

        public function initialize(array $config)
        {
            $this->table('tipos_exercicios');

            $this->addAssociations([
                'hasMany' => [
                    'Atividades' => [
                        'className' => 'Atividades',
                        'foreignKey' => 'id_tipo_exercicio',
                        'bindingKey' => 'id',
                        'joinType' => 'INNER',
                        'dependent' => false,
                        'cascadeCallbacks' => false,
                        'propertyName' => '_atividades'
                    ]
                ]
            ]);
        }

    }
```

I'm doing this query:

```
$circuitos = $CircuitosTable->find('all', [
                        'conditions' => ['id_plano_treino' => $idPlano], 
                        'contain' => ['Atividades'],
                        'joins' => [
                                        [
                                            "table" => "Tiposexercicios",
                                            "alias" => "TipoExercicio",
                                            "type" => "INNER",
                                            "conditions" => ["TipoExercicio.id = Atividades.id_tipo_exericio"]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                        ]);
```

The expected result:

```
Select * From Circuitos
JOIN Atividades on Atividades.id_circuito = Circuitos.id
JOIN Tiposexercicios on Tiposexercicios.id = Atividades.id_tipo_exercicio
```

The submitted query does not work properly. How should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hasMany` associations are being queried using a separate query, so using `contain()` to include `Atividades` will not include the table in the main query.

It looks like you want to filter by associated data, so you can save yourself a lot of trouble by simply using `Query::matching()` or `Query::innerJoinWith()`. This will join in associated tables as needed.

The following would create a query similar to what you seem to be looking for:

```
$circuitos = $CircuitosTable
    ->find()
    ->innerJoinWith('Atividades.Tiposexercicios')
    ->where([
        'Circuitos.id_plano_treino' => $idPlano
    ])
    ->group('Circuitos.id');
```

```sql
SELECT 
  -- ...
FROM 
  circuitos Circuitos 
  INNER JOIN atividades Atividades
    ON Circuitos.id = (Atividades.id_circuito) 
  INNER JOIN tipos_exercicios Tiposexercicios
    ON Tiposexercicios.id = (Atividades.id_tipo_exercicio) 
WHERE 
  Circuitos.id_plano_treino = 123
GROUP BY 
  Circuitos.id
```

The grouping is required as you may otherwise receive duplicate results.

See also **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Filtering by Associated Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#filtering-by-associated-data)**

On a side note, the `table` key in the join definition is ment to hold the actual database table name, which, according to your table classes, is `tipos_exercicios`!

Comment: Perfect!
You saved all my problems !
I was really having trouble with using multiple relationships or more levels of bonds .
Thank you!

Comment: I'm still having a problem with this model I can only return the data ciruitos table. I tried using the - > Select to search all fields from all tables but did not work. The difficulty is being on how to return and read in the view.

Comment: @VainerCesario What is it that you actually want to do? Filtering by associated data? Retrieving associated data? Both?

Comment: Return data from all tables in the relationship.
As an example , would need to return the "nome" field of the " Circuitos" table , the field "tipo" table "Atividades" and the "nome" field of " Tipoexercicios " table and display on a listing in the view. My difficulty being to seek the data in the return array.